# XML parsing in Chrome vs IE and Firefox

Tags: jquery, xml, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

I'm using JQuery to parse some XML returned from a server, and using it to populate a table; unfortunately, this only works in Firefox and IE, but not Chrome. Relevant code below:

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
$(xmlDoc).find('z\\:row').each (
    function ()
    {//this stuff never gets executed in Chrome}
```

I've tried using $(xmlDoc).find("[nodeName=z:row]") as well, but that gives me an invalid syntax error. I've verified that xml, as passed to $.parseXML, is indeed a valid and complete XML document.

(The reason I'm looking for 'z:row' is that this is output from SharePoint Web Services.)

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Edit: Problem resolved. Turns out whoever posted the nodeName syntax on the site I was looking at posted invalid syntax. It needs to be '[nodeName="z:row"]' to be a self-contained string, all quotes mandatory. * shakes head *

Comment: i'm working with xml right now, my stuff's is pretty much the same like yours, i have to return values from server, and populate inputs, but instead use jquery, i'm using php. check this out ( http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial156_How-to-read-XML-using-PHP-DOM.html )

Comment: Glad you solved the problem. If you post the solution as an answer and mark it as accepted, it will help others who may find it while searching in the future.  :)

Comment: Haha, I feel your pain. I wish browser developers would just follow the same coding standards so we could avoid this mess... I found out that Chrome just doesn't support z\\:row. As in, it just plain doesn't recognize it. * miffed *

Spudley, will do, but my rep isn't high enough to self-respond for 8 hours. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved. Turns out whoever posted the nodeName syntax on the site I was looking at posted invalid syntax. It needs to be '[nodeName="z:row"]' to be a self-contained string, all quotes mandatory. * shakes head *

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem lies in the line break after `function()`

JavaScript has implicit semicolon insertion after a line. On some browsers they can tell that a `function()` shouldn't get a line break, however in the ECMAScript standard it's not there.

Do `function(){` (move the `{` up)

Edit: Oh if it is resolved, then ignore the above. However it's still good to follow a development guide such as the http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml

Comment: Whoa, I had *no* idea about this... Will definitely keep this in mind for the future. :)

Comment: Yeah. Read through that Google style documentation. It tells you a lot (also helps if you want to use the closure compiler). Also statements such as `if (something)` should be followed by a `{` on the same line. So `if (something){`. I do it anyway in all language as i find it cleaner :P